# Swift - how can I add extend an existing class with new properties?

Tags: swift, inheritance

I want to create a subclass of GMSMarker. It initialises with one property which is `position: CLLocationCoordinate2D`. It also has properties which can be set like this

```
let position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.5, -0.127)
let london = GMSMarker(position: position)
london.title = "London"
london.icon = UIImage(named: "house")
london.map = mapView
```

I want to add new property `rating`

I tried like this

```
class Marker: GMSMarker {

var rating:Int

init(rating: Int){
    self.rating = rating
    super.init()
}

}
```

But it doesn't allow assign value to property `rating` by using dot notation

How can I do this ?

Comment: What is GMSMarker, exactly?

Comment: @matt It's from Google Maps: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_marker

Answer (score 0):

Change it as follows :

```
    var rating : Int = 0

convenience init(rating: Int){
    self.init()
    self.rating = 2

}
```

Swift requires that all properties are fully intialized, before the instance is create.

Also, when you write a convenience initializer, like you are doing here, the convenience initializer can only call another convenience initializer or a designated initializer **within** the same class.

Comment: `self.init()` won't work in this case because GMSMarker has a required `position` argument in its initializer.